# Lock wait timeout on one server but not another

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a database update which works on one server but fails on another. The working server is Windows 10 running MySQL 5.7.27 while the other is Linux running MySQL 5.7.26. On both servers there is only a single user, so there cannot be any conflicts with other processes.

I have tried copying exactly the same data from the Linux server to the Windows server to see if it as data problem, but the Windows server never fails.

After the transaction I execute two SELECTS as shown below:
-- QUERY #1

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS invoice_item.*, invoice_header.party_id_bill_from, invoice_header.currency_code_tx, invoice_header.currency_code_fn, invoice_header.exchange_rate, invoice_header.invoice_date, invoice_header.tax_date, invoice_header.party_id_bill_to, invoice_header.invoice_status_type_id, invoice_header.order_type, invoice_header.order_id, price_component.price_type, product.product_name, product.inventory_type, product.product_subtype, product.uom_id, product.is_revision_controlled, unit_of_measure.uom_desc, unit_of_measure.uom_abbrev, COALESCE(scale, 0) AS uom_scale, party_name AS party_name_bill_to, ROUND((quantity * adjusted_price)     - (COALESCE(invoice_item.free_units,0)  * unit_price)    , 3) AS item_value, ROUND((quantity * adjusted_price_tx)  - (COALESCE(invoice_item.free_units,0)  * unit_price_tx) , 3) AS item_value_tx, adjusted_price    - (unit_price    + COALESCE(feature_price   , 0) ) AS item_adjustment, adjusted_price_tx - (unit_price_tx + COALESCE(feature_price_tx, 0) ) AS item_adjustment_tx  
FROM invoice_item  
LEFT JOIN invoice_header ON (invoice_header.invoice_type=invoice_item.invoice_type AND invoice_header.invoice_id=invoice_item.invoice_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_product".price_component ON (price_component.price_component_id=invoice_item.price_component_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_product".product ON (product.product_id=invoice_item.product_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_product".unit_of_measure ON (unit_of_measure.uom_id=invoice_item.uom_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_party".party AS party_bill_to ON (party_bill_to.party_id=invoice_header.party_id_bill_to)  
WHERE invoice_item.invoice_type= 'V' 
  AND invoice_item.invoice_id= 2856045177200000000000000000000000001 
  AND invoice_item.invoice_item_seq_no= '2'    
ORDER BY invoice_item.invoice_id, invoice_item.invoice_item_seq_no asc  
FOR UPDATE
```

-- QUERY #2

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS invoice_account_item.*, invoice_account_header.journal_desc, invoice_account_header.uom_id_statistic AS uom_id_statistic_header, gl_account.account_id_formatted, gl_account.account_name, invoice_adjustment.adjustment_seq_no AS invoice_adjustment_seq_no, invoice_adjustment.adjustment_desc AS invoice_adjustment_desc, invoice_header.party_id_bill_from, invoice_header.party_id_bill_to, invoice_header.currency_code_fn, invoice_header.currency_code_tx, invoice_header.exchange_rate, invoice_header.adjusted_value_tx, invoice_header.invoice_status_type_id, invoice_item.invoice_item_desc, invoice_item_adjustment.adjustment_seq_no AS invoice_item_adjustment_seq_no, invoice_item_adjustment.adjustment_desc AS invoice_item_adjustment_desc, invoice_item_feature.prod_feature_id AS invoice_item_prod_feature_id  
FROM invoice_account_item  
LEFT JOIN invoice_account_header ON (invoice_account_header.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_account_header.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_finance_gl".gl_account ON (gl_account.chart_id=invoice_account_item.chart_id 
      AND gl_account.account_id=invoice_account_item.account_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_invoice".invoice_adjustment ON (invoice_adjustment.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_adjustment.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id 
      AND invoice_adjustment.adjustment_seq_no=invoice_account_item.invoice_adjustment_seq_no)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_invoice".invoice_header ON (invoice_header.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_header.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_invoice".invoice_item ON (invoice_item.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_item.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id 
      AND invoice_item.invoice_item_seq_no=invoice_account_item.invoice_item_seq_no)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_invoice".invoice_item_adjustment ON (invoice_item_adjustment.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_item_adjustment.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id 
      AND invoice_item_adjustment.invoice_item_seq_no=invoice_account_item.invoice_item_seq_no 
      AND invoice_item_adjustment.adjustment_seq_no=invoice_account_item.invoice_item_adjustment_seq_no)  
LEFT JOIN "gmx9_invoice".invoice_item_feature ON (invoice_item_feature.invoice_type=invoice_account_item.invoice_type 
      AND invoice_item_feature.invoice_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_id 
      AND invoice_item_feature.invoice_item_seq_no=invoice_account_item.invoice_item_seq_no 
      AND invoice_item_feature.prod_feature_id=invoice_account_item.invoice_item_prod_feature_id)  
WHERE invoice_account_item.invoice_type= 'V' 
  AND invoice_account_item.invoice_id= 2856045177200000000000000000000000001 
  AND invoice_account_item.invoice_item_seq_no= '2'     
LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

On the Windows 10 server the 2nd SELECT works, but on the Linux server it fails with "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Comment: loook here for a solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100984/mysql-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction

Comment: I have tried changing the innodb_lock_wait_timeout setting, but this does not solve the problem. As I mentioned at the start of my post there is only a single user accessing this system, so there ae no other user processes which could cause a locking conflict.

Comment: I have also tried reducing the failing second query to a shorter  `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *  FROM invoice_account_item  WHERE invoice_account_item.invoice_type= 'V' AND invoice_account_item.invoice_id= 30303000000000000000000000000011 AND invoice_account_item.invoice_item_seq_no= '2'     LOCK IN SHARE MODE`  but this does not make a difference.

Comment: you could check all the server variables of both systems , if there are differences. How much Did you increase it 600 ?

Comment: There is only a single process running, so there is not a lock in another process which can cause a conflict. Changing the innodb_lock_wait_timeout value does not make any difference.

Comment: There are many limiting factors for sql statement every join looks up both sides to see if there fullfill the on clause this needs ram and lots of cpu power for every run. So first check if both systems have the same configuration for this check all server variables and then increase . If both are equal increase everything that You can find till it works and please it doesn't matter how many people are at the same time on the system.

Comment: If the system ran out of memory while trying to apply a lock then I would expect the error message to say so. I cannot find anywhere in the manual which identifies which variables are used during locking, so I don't know which variables to check.